# Plotting both points and lines separately from pandas data that contains x, y, id columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have some panda data with columns containing `x`, `y` data and `id's` so basically representing each point of a graph with its `id` as pointer to which graph the points belongs.
I am plotting the data with mathplotlib.

```
for i in df_path.id.unique():
    x = df_path[df_path.id==i]['x']
    y = df_path[df_path.id==i]['y']
    if(df_path['id'].value_counts()==1):
        point=pd.DataFrame({'x': [x], 'y': [y]})
        point.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, style='bx', label='point')
    else:
        plt.plot(x-1, y-1)
```

Now it happens that single points can not be displayed and I am trying to handle this with the `if clause` to separate lines from points in order to be able to plot them both.
I want to do that by counting wether the `id` only occurs once in the panda table. this implements it is a single point not a line. Somehow the `value_count()` method does not work how i want it to work. 
Anyone having an idea how to fix it?

Data looks like:

```
"x"  "y" "id"
 3    4    0
 1    2    1
 1    3    1
 1    4    1
```

In this case I would like to get the row with `0 id` as a point to plot it and the `1 id` as a line.

Comment: The 1 `id` is a vertical line?

Comment: in this case yes but could be any line. it was just some example data to make clear what i mean with point and line. Line --> several rows with same id. Point--> only 1 occurrence of an id

Comment: First save all the point fulfilling the if statement in some list. Once you are outside the for loop, plot them all at once.

Comment: good point @Bazingaa! true i should do that. anyways, the count_value() method returns a list of all id's and it is count. do you know how to just get the one row that  has an id that only appears once in all the column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, g in df.groupby('id'):
    g.plot(x='x',y='y', marker='o', ax=ax, label=name)
```

Output:

[image]